# Java - Proper Way To Initialize an Autowired Service

Tags: spring-boot, autowired

I have inherited a springboot application. This application has a service similar to the following:

```
@Service
public class MyService {
String param1 = "";
String param2 = "";

    public void doStuff() {
        // do stuff assuming the parameters param1 and param 2 of this autowired service have already been initialized
   }
}
```

, This service is autowired from another service similar to the following;

```
@Service
public MainService {

@Autowired MyService myService;

    public performWork() {

       this.myService.doStuff();
    }
}
```

, and finally, the springboot app is similar to the following. The calling of the listen() method happens once the Kafka topic has a message (Kafka is only here relevant here because it kicks off the calling of the autowired services):

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {

@Autowired
MainService mainService;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

            SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }


    @KafkaListener(topics = "myTopic")
    public void listen(String message) {

        this.graphicService.performWork();

     }
}
```

Here is my question: What is a proper way to have the parameters param1 and param2 already initialized on the MyService service before its doStuff() method is called?

I would instead NOT use a bean configuration file, but rather have it performed as part of the starting of the springboot app. Any advice is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per my understanding, you just want to execute initialization statements at your bean's initialization. You can use `PostConstruct` annotation for any work you need to do as soon as beans are created.

`MyService` class should look like the following

```
@Service
public class MyService {

    String param1;
    String param2;

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstructRoutine() {
        // initialize parameters
        param1 = "some_value";
        param2 = "some_other_value";
    }

    public void doStuff() {
        // do stuff
   }

}
```

The `PostConstruct` annotation is used on a method that needs to be executed **after dependency injection is done** to perform any initialization.

You can find more info about the annotation at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html).

As a side note, it is always better to use constructor injection instead of `Autowired`. I would highly recommend it.

Comment: Thanks. The PostConstruct worked for me.